# Tibco EMS - File to Database Configuration issue with JVM

Tags: database, tibco, ems

I am configuring Tibco EMS 7.0 server on Solaris 10 from the default file based store to a Database Store (Oracle RAC).  Starting the instance the log shows the following JVM error:

```
2014-09-18 14:34:36.729 Logging into file '/lcl/dev/logs/tibco/jmspm2.log'
2014-09-18 14:34:36.729 ERROR: Error Loading JVM: ld.so.1: tibemsd64: fatal: /lcl/dev   /apps/tibco/components/eclipse/_jvm/lib/sparc/libjvm.so/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so: Not a directory
```

- I have installed hibernate 3.2.5.001 from Tibco that uses the Eclipse JVM and files. Also istalled the recommended instantclient_11_2 that includes ojdbc5.
- Below is my modified tibemsd.conf with dbstore_classpath, dbstore_driver_name, dbstore_driver_dialect, jre_library as:

  dbstore_classpath = /lcl/dev/apps/tibco/components/eclipse/plugins/com.tibco.tpcl.org.hibernate_3.2.5.001/hibernate3.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/ems/7.0/bin/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/ems/7.0/bin/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/ems/7.0/bin/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/ems/7.0/bin/ehcache-1.2.3.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/jta.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/ems/7.0/bin/cglib-2.1.3.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/antlr-2.7.6.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/ems/7.0/bin/antlr-2.7.6.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/components/eclipse/plugins/com.tibco.tpcl.org.com.mchange.c3p0_0.9.1.001/c3p0-0.9.1.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco//ems/7.0/bin/asm.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/asm-attrs.jar;/lcl/dev/apps/tibco;../db_components/instantclient_11_2/ojdbc5.jar

  dbstore_driver_name  = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  dbstore_driver_dialect  = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  jre_library = /lcl/dev/apps/tibco/components/eclipse/_jvm/lib/sparc/libjvm.so
- I get the same error when I installed jdk1.5.0_71 and attempted to call ./jdk1.5.0_71/jre/lib/sparc/libjvm.so
- I get the same error when set jre_library to: /lcl/dev/apps/tibco/components/eclipse/_jvm/lib/sparc since it appears to be looking for a directory.

Questions:

- Is the ld.so.1 libray required (can't find it)?
- Any ideas how to resolve this error and configure Java?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I installed Java 1.6 via jdk1.6.0_45 and it worked!  Below are the JRE settings that were used.

```
# jre_library = "/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so"  # This also works
jre_library = "/lcl/dev/apps/tibco/jdk1.6.0_45/jre"  # This path works too, more consise
jre_option = -Xmx256m
```